# Performance impact of objects

Tags: c++, c, performance

I am a beginner programmer with some experience at c and c++ programming. I was assigned by the university to make a physics simulator, so as you might imagine there's a big emphasis on performance.

My questions are the following:

1. How many assembly instructions does an instance data member access
   through a pointer translate to (i.e for an example vector->x )?
2. Is it much more then say another approach where you simply access the
   memory through say a char* (at the same memory location of variable
   x), or is it the same?
3. Is there a big impact on performance
   compiler-wise if I use an object to access that memory location or
   if I just access it?
4. Another question regarding the subject would be
   whether or not accessing heap memory is faster then stack memory
   access?

Comment: C combines performance of an assembly language with the flexibility of an assembly language.

Comment: There are at least two different topics here; please constrain yourself to one topic per SO post.  Thanks.

Comment: I concur with Oli. One question per question, please.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is a compiled language. Accessing a memory location through a pointer is the same regardless of whether that's a pointer to an object or a pointer to a `char*` - it's one instruction in either case. There are a couple of spots where C++ adds overhead, but it always buys you some flexibility. For example, invoking a virtual function requires an extra level of indirection. However, you would need the same indirection anyway if you were to emulate the virtual function with function pointers, or you would spend a comparable number of CPU cycles if you were to emulate it with a `switch` or a sequence of `if`s.

In general, you should not start optimizing before you *know* what part of your code to optimize. Usually only a small part of your code is responsible for the bulk of the CPU time used by your program. You do not know what part to optimize until you profile your code. Almost universally it's programmer's code, not the language features of C++, that is responsible for the slowdown. The only way to know for sure is to profile.

Comment: +1 I program games with C++, so I run into problems concerning performance frequently. To this day I have yet to ever have an issue with performance directly because of C++. Every single time it was because of how it was used. You can't beat better logic.

Answer (score 3):

1. On x86, a pointer access is typically one extra instruction, above and beyond what you normally need to perform the operation (e.x. `y = object->x;` would be one load of the address in `object`, and one load of the value of `x`, and one store to `y` - in x86 assembler both loads and stores are `mov` instructions with memory target). Sometimes it's "zero" instructions, because the compiler can optimise away the load of the object pointer. In other architectures, it's really down to how the architecture works - some architectures have very limited ways of accessing memory and/or loading addresses to pointers, etc, making it awkward to access pointers.
2. Exactly the same number of instructions - this applies for all
3. As #2 - objects in themselves have no impact at all.
4. Heap memory and stack memory is the same kind. One answer says that "stack memory is always in the caceh", which is true if it's "near the top of the stack", where all the activity goes on, but if you have an object that is being passed around that was created in `main`, and a pointer to it is used to pass it around for several layers of function calls, and then access through the pointer, there is an obvious chance that this memory hasn't been used for a long while, so there is no real difference there either). The big difference is that "heap memory is plenty of space, stack is limited" along with "running out of heap is possible to do limited recovery, running out of stack is immediate end of execution [without tricks that aren't very portable]"

If you look at `class` as a synonym for `struct` in C (which aside from some details, they really are), then you will realize that `class` and objects are not really adding any extra "effort" to the code generated.

Of course, used correctly, C++ can make it much easier to write code where you deal with things that are "do this in a very similar way, but subtly differently". In C, you often end up with :

```
   void drawStuff(Shape *shapes, int count)
   {
     for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
        switch (shapes[i].shapeType)
       {
       case Circle:
         ... code to draw a circle ... 
         break;
       case Rectangle:
         ... code to draw a rectangle ... 
         break;
       case Square:
         ... 
         break;
       case Triangle:
         ...
         break;
       }
     }
   }
```

In C++, we can do this at the object creation time, and your "drawStuff" becoems:

```
void drawStuff(std::vector<Shape*> shapes)
{
   for(auto s : shapes)
   {
      s->Draw();
   }
}
```

"Look Ma, no switch..." ;) 
(Of course, you do need a switch or something to do the selection of which object to create, but once choice is made, assuming your objects and the surrounding architecture are well defined, everything should work "magically" like the above example).

Finally, if it's IMPORTANT with performance, then run benchmarks, run profiling and check where the code is spending it's time. Don't optimise too early (but if you have strict performance criteria for something, keep an eye on it, because deciding on the last week of a project that you need to re-organise your data and code dramatically because performance sucks due to some bad decision is also not the best of ideas!). And don't optimise for individual instructions, look at where the time is spent, and come up with better algorithms WHERE you need to. (In the above example, using `const std::vector<Shape*>& shapes` will effectively pass a pointer to the shapes vector passed in, instead of copying the entire thing - which may make a difference if there are a few thousand elements in `shapes`).

Answer (score 1):

- It depends on your target architecture. An struct in C (and a class in C++) is just a block of memory containing the members in sequence. An access to such a field through a pointer means adding an offset to the pointer and loading from there. Many architectures allow a load to already specify an offset to the target address, meaning that there is no performance penalty there; but even on extreme RISC machines that don't have that, adding the offset should be so cheap that the load completely shadows it.
- Stack and heap memory are really the same thing. Just different areas. Their basic access speed is therefore the same. The main difference is that the stack will most likely already be in the cache no matter what, whereas heap memory might not be if it hasn't been accessed lately.

Comment: Accessing data "on the heap" invariably requires a pointer dereference at some point; accessing data "on the stack" more often does not.

Comment: Sure it does - you need to dereference the stack pointer. Which is in a register, true, but still a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable. On most processors instructions are translated to something called microcode, similar to how Java bytecode are translated to processor-specific instructions before you run it. How many actual instructions you get are different between different processor manufacturers and models.
2. Same as above, it depends on processor internals most of us know little about.

1+2. What you should be asking are how many clock cycles these operations take. On modern platforms the answer are one. It does not matter how many instructions they are, a modern processor have optimizations to make both run on one clock cycle. I will not get into detail here. I other words, when talking about CPU load there are no difference at all.

1. Here you have the tricky part. While there are no difference in how many clock cycles the instruction itself take, it needs to have data from memory before it can run - this can take a HUGE ammount of clock cycles. Actually someone proved a few years ago that even with a very optimized program a x86 processor spends at least 50% of its time waiting for memory access.
2. When you use stack memory you are actually doing the same thing as creating an array of structs. For the data, instructions are not duplicated unless you have virtual functions. This makes data aligned and if you are going to do sequential access, you will have optimal cache hits. When you use heap memory you will create an array of pointers, and each object will have its own memory. This memory will NOT be aligned and therefore sequential access will have a lot of cache misses. And cache misses are what really will your application slower and should be avoided at all cost.

I do not know exactly what you are doing but in many cases even using objects are much slower than plain arrays. An array of objects are aligned [object1][object2] etc. If you do something like pseudocode "for each object o {o.setX() = o.getX() + 1}"... this means that you will only access one variable and your sequential access would therefore jump over the other variables in each object and get more cache misses than if your X-variables where aligned in their own array. And if you have code that use all variables in your object, standard arrays will not be slower than object array. It will just load the different arrays into different cache blocks.

While standard arrays are faster in C++ they are MUCH faster in other languages like Java, where you should NEVER store bulk data in objects - as Java objects use more memory and are always stored at the heap. This are the most common mistake that C++ programmers do in Java, and then complain that Java are slow. However if they know how to write optimal C++ programs they store data in arrays which are as fast in Java as in C++.

What I usually do are a class to store the data, that contains arrays. Even if you use the heap, its just one object which becomes as fast as using the stack. Then I have something like "class myitem { private: int pos; mydata data; public getVar1() {return data.getVar1(pos);}}". I do not write out all of the code here, just illustrating how I do this. Then when I iterate trough it the iterator class do not actually return a new myitem instance for each item, it increase the pos value and return the same object. This means you get a nice OO API while you actually only have a few objects and and nicely aligned arrays. This pattern are the fastest pattern in C++ and if you don't use it in Java you will know pain.

The fact that we get multiple function calls do not really matter. Modern processors have something called branch prediction which will remove the cost of the vast majority of those calls. Long before the code actually runs the branch predictor will have figured out what the chains of calls do and replaced them with a single call in the generated microcode.

Also even if all calls would run each would take far less clock cycles the memory access they require, which as I pointed out makes memory alignment the only issue that should bother you.